# Is it possible to have palm detection in Ubuntu? (Dell xps 9343) (Ubuntu 15.10 - Gnome DE)

Tags: drivers, dell, touchpad

Is it at all possible to have a simple feature like Palm detection in Ubuntu? I've been struggling with this for a year now. Nothing helps. BIOS update from Dell helped the matter but an Ubuntu update brought the issue back.

Blacklisting **i2c_hid**  in  `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`  does not help. Not blacklisting it does not help either.

Activating the Palm detection option in `xinput` for `DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD UNKNOWN` does not work too.

Switching to Libinput does bring palm detection into life but it makes my cursor all jumpy and crazy and any change in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-libinput.conf`  kills my login screen (all I get is a gray screen)

Is there a way to make it work? Why does it work perfect in Windows on my Virtualbox and not on the Linux system (I have to start Windows in Vbox so I could write letters because it's a nightmare to do it in Ubuntu). 
Is it a known issue with the community and how to make it so if it is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This shows a couple of comments where it seems to work: https://github.com/advancingu/XPS13Linux/issues/3

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the reply! Have read it - patching kernels is still on my list to learn. 
Found this today thou `syndaemon -i 2 -tKRd`. It seems to be working but with some glitches like loosing cursor whatsoever even after you finish typing.

Comment: this is not a good solution, i don't know if palm detection setting is there, why it wouldn't work. just tried in ubuntu 17.10 and it still doesn't work, did you find any solutions